# textarea expanded with jquery, not submitting the form when i click the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

I want the button to submit the form while the textarea is expanded. How do i do this?

The problem is that when I click the Post button in the form, while the textarea is expanded, it does not submit the form, instead it shrinks back down, and I need to click it again while it is smaller, to submit the form.

Currently in order to submit the post, i need to click the post button while the textarea is not expanded.

**HTML**

```
<form method='POST' action='elsewhere.php'>
    <textarea id="textarea" style="width:550px; height:25px;"></textarea>
    <input class="btn" type='submit' value='Post'/>                             
</form>
```

**jquery**

Currently when I click the text area, the height expands, and when i click elsewhere it shrinks. when i click the post button, while the textarea is expanded it doesnt submit the post, intead it shrinks the textarea back down.

```
$('#textarea').click(function(){
    $(this).css('height','100px')
    $(this).html('');
    $(this).blur(function(){
        $(this).css('height','25px')

    });
})
```

Comment: I think its some `z-index` related issue. Try giving `position: relative; z-index:1` to the submit button.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) it for testing

Comment: @arboles, did you tried my suggestion!! recently i have faced similar kind of issue.

Comment: @itsnotme where is your suggestions?

Comment: Its the first comment and last answer...

Comment: ok i see it now. i will try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I think its some z-index related issue. Try giving `position: relative; z-index:1;` to the submit button.</strike>

<strike>If you have set `z-index` for the `textarea` or any of its ancestors, increment that value by one and set it to the button.</strike>

<strike>There is a chance of the button being overlapped by the textarea while increasing its height.</strike>
<strike>And you too mentioned that, `while the textarea is expanded it doesnt submit the post`. It may be because of the button is overlapped.</strike>

**Update:**

I got it after

**The problem is that when I click the Post button in the form, while the textarea is expanded, it does not submit the form, instead it shrinks back down, and I need to click it again while it is smaller, to submit the form.**

```
$('#textarea').click(function(){
$(this).css('height','100px')
$(this).html('');
$(this).blur(function(){
    if(this.value === ''){
        $(this).css('height','25px')
    }

});
});
```

Comment: Can somebody explain about the -1?

Comment: @arboles. No, the guy is *trying* to help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are submitting the form and redirecting to another page, all you need is for the button to stay still long enogh to register the click, a timeout solves that problem:

```
$('#textarea').on({
    focus: function() {
        $(this).css('height','100px').html('');
    },
    blur: function() {
        var self = this,
            T = setTimeout(function() {$(self).css('height','25px') }, 200);
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/hpyTk/1/)

If using this with Ajax, and not redirecting, and to make the textarea not respond to the click on the button, you could use a variable to keep track of what element was clicked, and do somewhat the same as above:

```
var elm;

$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    elm = e.target;
    e.preventDefault();
    //do ajax stuff
});

$('#textarea').on({
    focus: function() {
        $(this).css('height','100px').html('');
    },
    blur: function() {
        var self = this,
            T = setTimeout(function() {
                if ($(elm).attr('class') != 'btn') $(self).css('height','25px');
            }, 200);
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/hpyTk/3/)

Comment: can i mark both answers as correct? since this method worked in addition to the other method. i marked the other one as the answer since he answered first.

Comment: That's up to you, but the other answer is wrong, it has nothing to do with position or z-index, the textarea is not overlapping the button, but the blur function occurs so fast that the click on the button is not registered because the button moves before you actually click it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue the other day, and what was happening was that the `blur` event on the textarea was occurring *before* the browser took into consideration the `click` event on the button.

Thus, in order, I was clicking on the button, THEN the browser fired the `blur` event on the textarea, shrinking it and moving the button, THEN the browser took the click in consideration, doing nothing because there was no longer a button where I clicked.

I did not directly fix the problem, though, deciding that I would shrink the textarea only if it was not empty (adding some `this.value == this.defaultValue || this.value == ''` test in the `blur` event).